# Cookie Clicker Saving Mechanic

Tags: javascript, html, save, loading

I have recently finished the JavaScript and HTML tutorials on CodeCademy.  To try and further improve my knowledge of both languages, I started to make my own version of "Cookie Clicker" and am stumped.  I need a way to save game data when a player leaves the browser.  I have seen many ways as to how to go about this, but despite my best efforts, I cannot find out how to use the localSave(); command to save and load my game data.  Any suggestions *and explanations* on how to go about doing this would be appreciated.  I intend to try and make more games in the future as I found remaking the basics of Cookie Clicker to be quite fun, so understand how to use localSave will be quite important to me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cookie Clicker</title>
    <link type="stylesheet/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script language="javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Cookie Clickers By: Michael</h1>
    <h3>Original Idea By: Orteil</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1 id="CookieAmount"></h1>
    <h2 id="CookiePerSecond"></h2>
    <div id="cookie" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="cookieClicked();"><img     src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130827014912/cookieclicker/images/thumb/5/5a/PerfectCookie.png/250px-PerfectCookie.png"></div>
    <!--Tells player how much upgrade Costs-->
    <button onclick="getAutoClicker();">Purchase Auto Clicker for <span id="AutoClickCookieCost"></span></button>
    <button onclick="getGrandma();">Purchase Grandma for <span id="GrandmaCookieCost"></span></button>
    <button onclick="getFarm();">Purchase Farm for <span id="FarmCookieCost"></span></button>
    <button onclick="getFactory();">Purchase Factory for <span id="FactoryCookieCost"></span></button>
    <button onclick="getMine();">Purchase Mine for <span id="MineCookieCost"></span></button>
    
    <div>
   <script language="javascript">
    //variables:
    var cookieClicks = 0;
    var clickValue = 1
       
    var AutoClickers = 0;
    var AutoClickerCost = 50;   
       
    var Grandmas = 0;
    var GrandmaCost= 500;
       
    var Farms = 0;
    var FarmCost = 2500
    
    var Factories = 0;
    var FactoryCost = 5000;
       
    var Mines = 0;
    var MineCost = 10000;
       //Processes cookie click and adds it to total.
    function cookieClicked() {
        cookieClicks++;
    }
       //Purchases Auto Clicker for Player and removes Cookies.
       function getAutoClicker(){
           if(cookieClicks >= AutoClickerCost){
               AutoClickers++;
               cookieClicks -= AutoClickerCost;
               AutoClickerCost += Math.floor(AutoClickerCost*.3);
           }else{
               alert("Oh No!  It appears you do not have enough cookies to purchase an Auto Clicker.  An Auto Clicker currently costs "+AutoClickerCost+" which is "+(AutoClickerCost-cookieClicks)+" more cookies than you have.")
           }
       }
       //Purchase Grandma and remove Cookie Cost.
       function getGrandma(){
           if(cookieClicks >= GrandmaCost){
               Grandmas++;
               cookieClicks -= GrandmaCost;
               GrandmaCost += Math.floor(GrandmaCost*.3);
           }else{
               alert("Oh No!  It appears you do not have enough cookies to purchase a Grandma.  A Grandma currently costs "+GrandmaCost+" which is "+(GrandmaCost-cookieClicks)+" more cookies than you have.")
           }
       }
       //Purchase Farm and remove Cookie Cost.
       function getFarm(){
           if(cookieClicks >= FarmCost){
               Farms++;
               cookieClicks -= FarmCost;
               FarmCost += Math.floor(FarmCost*.3);
           }else{
               alert("Oh No!  It appears you do not have enough cookies to purchase a Farm.  A Farm currently costs "+FarmCost+" which is "+(FarmCost-cookieClicks)+" more cookies than you have.")
           }
       }
       //Purchase Factory and remove Cookie Cost.
       function getFactory(){
           if(cookieClicks >= FactoryCost){
               Factories++;
               cookieClicks -= FactoryCost;
               FactoryCost += Math.floor(FactoryCost*.3);
           }else{
               alert("Oh No!  It appears you do not have enough cookies to purchase a Factory.  A Factory currently costs "+FactoryCost+" which is "+(FactoryCost-cookieClicks)+" more cookies than you have.")
           }
       }
       //Purchase Mine and remove COokie Cost.
       function getMine(){
           if(cookieClicks >= MineCost){
               Mines++;
               cookieClicks -= MineCost;
               MineCost += Math.floor(MineCost*.3)
           }else{
               alert("Oh No!  It appears you do not have enough cookies to purchase a Mine.  A Mine currently costs "+MineCost+" which is "+(MineCost-cookieClicks)+" more cookies than you have.")
           }
       }
       //Main Game loop updating Cookie Totals from AUTOCLICKER ONLY!
var AutoClickTimer = setInterval(function () {AutoClickCookie()}, 2000);
       function AutoClickCookie(){
           cookieClicks += AutoClickers;
       }
       //Main Game loop update Cookie Totals from ALL OTHER STRUCUTERS.
var AllStructureTimer = setInterval(function(){StructureCookie},1000)
    function StructureCookie(){
           cookieClicks += (Grandmas*5);
           cookieClicks += (Farms*20);
           cookieClicks += (Factories*60);
           cookieClicks += (Mines*100);
    }
        //Side Loop updating button costs and CPS
       var CookieClickTimer = setInterval(function() {updateCookie()}, 100);
       function updateCookie(){
           //Calculate CPS
           var CPS = (AutoClickers*.5)+(Grandmas*5)+(Farms*20)+(Factories*60)+(Mines*100);
            document.getElementById("CookieAmount").innerHTML = cookieClicks+" cookies.";
            document.getElementById("CookiePerSecond").innerHTML = CPS+" CPS.";
            document.getElementById("AutoClickCookieCost").innerHTML = AutoClickerCost;
            document.getElementById("GrandmaCookieCost").innerHTML = GrandmaCost;
            document.getElementById("FarmCookieCost").innerHTML = FarmCost;
            document.getElementById("FactoryCookieCost").innerHTML = FactoryCost;
            document.getElementById("MineCookieCost").innerHTML = MineCost;
       }
//unfinished loop I will use in future (ignore it)
       var CookieClickValueTimer = setInterval(function(){updateCookieValue()},100);
    
</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I apologize if any of the code is hard to follow.  I am new to this, so everything could definitely be done a lot better.

**EDIT** Here is one of my attempts at using localStorage to save.  Unfortunately, it does not work.  If someone could explain why this does not work or what I could do to fix it, I'd appreciate it.

```js
if(localStorage.cookieClicks === null || " "){
    //If no variables are defined, the variables are defined and given a default value.
   var cookieClicks = 0;
   var clickValue = 1

   var AutoClickers = 0;
   var AutoClickerCost = 50;

   var Grandmas = 0;
   var GrandmaCost = 500;

   var Farms = 0;
   var FarmCost = 2500

   var Factories = 0;
   var FactoryCost = 5000;

   var Mines = 0;
   var MineCost = 10000;
    confirm("New Variables Created");
   } else if(localStorage.cookieClicks >= 0){
   var cookieClicks = localStorage.cookieClicks;
   var clickValue = localStorage.clickValue;

   var AutoClickers = localStorage.AutoClickers;
   var AutoClickerCost = localStorage.AutoClickerCost;

   var Grandmas = localStorage.Grandmas;
   var GrandmaCost = localStorage.GrandmaCost;

   var Farms = localStorage.Farms;
   var FarmCost = localStorage.FarmCost;

   var Factories = localStorage.Factories;
   var FactoryCost = localStorage.FactoryCost;

   var Mines = localStorage.Mines;
   var MineCost = localStorage.MineCost;
    confirm("Old Progress loaded!");
   }else
    alert("Something is broken!")
   }
            
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//The two main save/loading scripts
var saveGameLoop = setInterval(function(){saveGame()}, 100);
   function saveGame(){
    localStorage.cookieClicks = cookieClicks;
    localStorage.clickValue = clickValue;
    
    localStorage.AutoClickers = AutoClickers;
    localStorage.AutoClickerCost = AutoClickerCost;
    
    localStorage.Grandmas = Grandmas;
    localStorage.GrandmaCost = GrandmaCost;
    
    localStorage.Farms = Farms;
    localStorage.FarmCost = FarmCost;
    
    localStorage.Factories = Factories;
    localStorage.FactoryCost = FactoryCost;
    
    localStorage.Mines = Mines;
    localStorage.MineCost = MineCost;
```

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: You can simply set cookies.

Comment: @ForceBru care to explain more?  I looked at cookies too but they seem really complicated on all the sites I visted for information.  I need someone to break all this down and explain it to a novice.

Comment: @ForceBru +1 just for the pun

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a rather old question, here's my answer..

I'll use [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) which is a "simple API for cross-browser local storage", so you need to include it in some way (there's also an npm-module).

In your `saveGame`-Function you would then need to use `store.set(KEY, VALUE)`,
e.g.:

```
store.set('cookieClicks', cookieClicks);
```

And to load the data, use `store.get(KEY)`, e.g.:

```
store.get('cookieClicks');
```

---

You maybe want to organize all those key a little bit more, so you could just save all the key's and value's in JSON-Format, e.g.:

```
store.set('Save 1', {
    "cookieClicks": cookieClicks, // The " around the key are optional if the key is in camelcase!
    "click-Value": clickValue // This would'nt work without "
});
```

This data would then be accessed like follows:

```
var sd = store.get('Save 1');
cookieClicks = sd.cookieClicks;

// or like this
clickValue= sd["click-Value"];
```